# Backing up with Google drive

Tags: latex, fuse, google-drive

I've recently switched from Windows to Linux, and have tried keeping certain things similar.  Mainly, I work in LaTeX a lot, and have stored all of my work in Google Drive.  With how Google Drive on windows works, this was at best imperfect (if while Latex was compiling a document google drive tried to sync, issues would arise), but it worked pretty well for the most part.

Now, I've switched over to a chromebook with GalliumOs, and have tried using Google Drive via OCamlfuse.  Unfortunately, this seems to make my compile times much longer (at least 10 seconds even for a simple document).  This makes this no longer an option for me, so it seems like I'll need to work locally.  Is there a way to still sync my files (even if it's only much more infrequently, or I need to trigger a sync manually) with google drive without storing the files in the directory that OCamlfuse mounts?

Comment: What you are after is to be able to work from several machines on the same documents, correct?  I'm pretty confident you are after a CVS (e.g. git).  Google drive is not meant to share source code between machines, a CVS is designed for that.

Comment: @grochmal after looking around, using Git does seem to be the best solution.